# is there an Oracle Http server setting needed to retain session data on a weblogic application server

Tags: oracle, apache, session, weblogic, session-variables

I work in a corporate environment. We have weblogic application servers and oracle http web servers (OHS) which is basically a modified apache web server. The OHS servers proxy the calls to the weblogic application servers which is where all our java code sites (war distribution). I have no access to the OHS servers to inspect any settings there.

I have a web application deployed on the application server and in the application.xml there was one context root that is pre-existing. Lets call this /roota. Im trying to add a second root context /rootb that will be able to hit the same URLs as /roota. to do this I just added  In the war I have a simple jsp that sets a session variable and also prints the same session variable:

/roota/testSession.jsp
/rootb/testSession.jsp

here is the application.xml configuration:

```
  <module id="webserver_internal">
      <web>
         <web-uri>appWeb</web-uri>
         <context-root>/roota</context-root>
      </web>
   </module>
  <module id="webserver_mobile">
      <web>
         <web-uri>appWeb</web-uri>
         <context-root>/rootb</context-root>
      </web>
  </module>
```

I can call both of them but for some reason the second page has a different session and does not seem to retain the session variables. If I call it using the app server URL the sessions work as expected but if I call it via the web server URL then it does not retain session data. The first URL /roota/testSession.jsp works fine using the web server URL or the app server URL. I can see the jsessionid is the same for both /roota and /rootb

Now my question. Is there some property in the OHS side that needs to be set in order for the session data to be retained?

Comment: Did you set a different cookie name for both applications ?

Comment: no- it uses the default cookie name and there is no domain path on the cookie